# How to edit the numpy array?

Tags: python, numpy

In python language, my numpy array is  ([12, 1]), and I want to divide it

```
the value is 
      ([[1],
        [2],
        [3],
        [4],
        [5],
        [6],
        [7],
        [8],
        [9],
        [10],
        [11],
        [12]])
```

and I want to make

```
       ([[1],[2],[3],[4]],
        [[5],[6],[7],[8]]
        [[9],[10],[11],[12]])
```

so I want to divid into thirds (so, the batch_size is 3)
how to make the code?

Answer (score 1):

Is it sufficient to reshape as `(3,4)`? Otherwise you may have `(3,4,1)`

```py
>>> arr.reshape(3,4)
array([[ 1,  2,  3,  4],
       [ 5,  6,  7,  8],
       [ 9, 10, 11, 12]])
>>> arr.reshape(3,4,1)
array([[[ 1],
        [ 2],
        [ 3],
        [ 4]],

       [[ 5],
        [ 6],
        [ 7],
        [ 8]],

       [[ 9],
        [10],
        [11],
        [12]]])
```

Answer (score -2):

```
original_array = [[1], [2], [3], [4], [5], [6], [7], [8], [9], [10], [11], [12]]

array1 = original_array[:4]
array2 = original_array[4:8]
array3 = original_array[8:]

print(array1)
print(array2)
print(array3)
```

Comment: Please read [answer] and [edit] your answer to contain an explanation as to why this code would actually solve the problem at hand. Always remember that you're not only solving the problem, but are also educating the OP and any future readers of this post